# How to make arrays values equal in C#?

Tags: c#, equals, arrays

Let's say that I have 2 string arrays with different values:
 `string[] sArray1 = new string[3]{"a","b","c"};

  string[] sArray2 = new string[3]{"e","f","g"}`

And I want to make values of `sArray1` equal to values of `sArray2` (I know I can write it like this) : `sArray1[0] = sArray2[0]; sArray1[1]= sArray2[1]; sArray1[2]=sArray2[2];`

For 3 values it's easy, but what if I had 100 values in an array? Is there any other way that I can make array values equal?

p.s. sorry for my bad English :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this (with a little error checking):

```
        if (sArray2.Length == sArray1.Length)
        {
            sArray2.CopyTo(sArray1, 0);    
        }
```

Regards

Comment: OMG, the OP actually streamlined me to think in a raw pattern. +1

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata It happens to me too. Thanks =)

Comment: I will create a facebook Page "I tried to answer with a for too". Great answer !

Comment: Wait a minute, I'm not sure this is what the OP wanted. Why would someone want to make array values equal? Why not `sArray1 = sArray2`? Anyway, I hope we'll find out, but I'd advise you update your answer to cover different scenarios...

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata `array1 = array2` would overwrite the object *reference*, not the values. If you read the question carefully, you'll notice that OP wants only the values, but keeping the original array reference

Comment: There is no practical difference between *making values of two arrays equal* and *making two arrays equal*.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata Actually, there is. A lot. I suppose that you're aware of `value types` and `reference types`. Are you?

Comment: @ Andre Calil is right, i want to keep original arrays. so lets say when i put "a" from sArray1 in textbox i want the program to show me "e" instead, in another textbox. and so goes for other values of arrays, i don't want it to be overwritten. (i hope this makes any sense tho :D) thx for the feedback :)

Comment: @user1563768 You are most welcome. Please, don't forget to mark answer as correct. However, if this is not the answer you are looking for, give me ane feedback so I can improve it. Regards

Comment: @AndreCalil yep this works, it gives me the values i wanted, one question tho: (sArray1, 0) in this line what is the 0 for? to tell C# to start from array value [0]? thx for answer again :)

Comment: @user1563768 Yes, its the starting index at the *destination* array. It's useful if the destination array is bigger than the source array.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata: There is a huge difference between having two variables of array type which identify the same array, versus having two variables which identify separate arrays with identical content.  For arrays of mutable reference types, there's a further distinction between distinct arrays that identify the same objects, versus distinct arrays that identify objects which have the same state.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to keep the reference to the original array in sArray1? Then do this:-

```
Array.Copy(sArray2, sArray1, sArray1.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to function independently of each other than you can use .Clone() as of .NET 5.0

```
string[] sArray1 = (string[])sArray2.Clone();
```

In the above scenario if you change a value in one array it will not affect the other - this is called a "shallow copy" (AKA copy by val). If you want the values in both arrays to be tied to each other (typically not desirable) you can do a simple assignment like this:

```
string[] sArray1 = sArray2;
```

In this case if you change a value in either array the value(s) in the other array will update (AKA copy by ref).